# What does the l equals to?

Tags: limits

I have got this limit and I have no clue how to resolve it:

$$l=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{ \sqrt[2018]{1+x}-\sqrt[2019]{1-x}}x $$

Can  you give me any tips or even resolve it please?

Comment: can you fix the LaTeX?

Comment: @ncmathsadist: Probably not, or he wouldn't have posted it that way. (But I'm reasonably sure _you_ can).

Comment: could I fix the LaTeX?

Comment: Ouch... x in the denominator....it suggests...limits value is infinity..unless there is a catch...

Comment: Yes please, fix the LaTeX!

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen After computing that should I sum them up?

Comment: I have to say, it’s very disappointing the way the community has responded to this post. You reprimand the typesetting, but offer no link to the [MathJax tutorial](https://goo.gl/OWv9nr); you downvote, but don’t offer a reason why. And even at that, you post multiple answers out of greed for, what, +15 rep? The OP isn’t merely posting a problem and expecting us to solve it; he’s **merely asking for tips**, and it’s not like this is a simple limit. I shall upvote to cancel out existing downvotes.

Comment: There was something I could not resolve looking at the LaTeX, and I am reluctant to change the meaning of the OP's question.  That's why I put the question.  And I did not downvote what seemed to be a legit post.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**
Compute $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sqrt[2018]{1+x}-\sqrt[2018]{1+0}}{x}$$
and
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sqrt[2019]{1-x}-\sqrt[2019]{1-0}}{x}$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** If you rewrite your expression to
$$ \frac{\sqrt[2018]{1+x}-1}x - \frac{\sqrt[2019]{1-x}-1}x $$
the limit decomposes into the difference of two derivatives

Answer (score 0):

If you know how to compute the derivative of $\sqrt[2018]{1+x}$ then [de L'hôpital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule) gives you a straightforward answer.

Answer (score 0):

use L'H,

## $\;\;\;\;\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sqrt[2018]{1+x}-\sqrt[2018]{1-x}}{x}$

## $=\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\frac{1}{2018(1+x)^{\frac{2017}{2018}}}+\frac{1}{2018(1-x)^{\frac{2017}{2018}}}}{1}$

## $=\frac{1}{2018}+\frac{1}{2018}$

## $=\color{blue}{\frac{1}{1009}}$

Answer (score 0):

$n:=2018$, then $n+1=2019$.

$f(x) =\dfrac{(1+x)^{1/n}-1}{x} -$

$\dfrac{(1-x)^{1/(n+1)} -1}{x}$.

1) $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \dfrac{(1+x)^{1/n} -1}{x}=(1/n)$

2) $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \dfrac{(1-x)^{1/(n+1)}-1}{x}=$

$-1/(n+1).$

Note : The limits are the derivatives of the resp. functions at $x=0$.

Combining:

$ \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} f(x)= 1/n+1/(n+1)$.